# Fixed-Size Square grid in Leaflet Map at Different Latitudes

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm attempting to generate square-shaped grid on a Leaflet map, similar to what you can see on this example: https://app.nextearth.io/. My primary goal is to ensure that these squares remain a fixed size and always appear in the same geographic location.

I've scoured for relevant code and almost found a solution. However, there's a fundamental issue with the existing code: as you move away from the equator towards the poles, the squares lose their square shape and become wider. This distortion in shape occurs due to the map projection.
I'm seeking a way to maintain square shapes across various latitudes on the map.

**This is my function to render the squares:**

```
const mapBounds: LatLngBounds = action.payload;
const tiles = [];

const tileSize = 1 / 111139 * 100;

const rowstart = Math.floor(mapBounds.getSouthWest().lat / tileSize);
const colstart = Math floor(mapBounds.getSouthWest().lng / tileSize);
const rowend = Math.floor(mapBounds.getNorthEast().lat / tileSize);
const colend = Math.floor(mapBounds.getNorthEast().lng / tileSize);

for (let row = rowstart; row <= rowend; row++) {
  for (let col = colstart; col <= colend; col++) {
    const bounds = new LatLngBounds(
      latLng(row * tileSize, col * tileSize),
      latLng((row + 1) * tileSize, (col + 1) * tileSize)
    );
    tiles.push({
      bounds
    });
  }
}
```

**primary goal:**
[image]

**The problem when moving away from the equator :**
[image]

I'm using react.js